# Python. reverse string in a function

Tags: python

```
def rev(somestring):


    if somestring is None:
        return somestring
    if (len(somestring)) <=1:
        return somestring

    return rev(somestring[1:]+somestring[0])

somestring = "house"
print(rev(somestring))
```

###does anyone know what I may be doing wrong

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: Typo: `return rev(somestring[1:]+somestring[0])` should be `return rev(somestring[1:])+somestring[0]`

Comment: Hint: try to run through your code with pencil and paper...

Comment: @Nick Typo? It's rather a misunderstanding... (but yes the question is definitely not searchable)

Comment: @user202729 pick your own reason... to me its the closest as it looks like a misplaced `)`

Comment: Next time, please provide your desire output for the code.

Comment: Thank you guys. I would note to put the desired output.

Comment: OP is forced to use a recursive function? If not, try ```something[::-1]```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you have `+ somestring[0]` inside the rev method invocation.
In other words change that line to...

```py
return rev(somestring[1:])+somestring[0]
```

Comment: I doubt this will help the op other than to submit the homework or something similar.

Comment: @user202729 this is the whole reason I wanted to close the question...

Comment: @user202729, I am learning how to code on my own . it is not for an Assignment. Thank you guys for the input